# Rails 6 Good Solution For Validating Entire Street Address

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, street-address

I have been searching for a while and so far I have not found a good solution for being able to make sure an entire street address is valid.

I already am able to validate ZIP Code and State but can't find a way to validate Address 1, Zip, state, and Country. The only things I found were paid solutions so I am curious if there are any free options or if its all behind a pay wall.

Comment: Hi John, welcome to SO! I think you're unlikely to get an answer to this question because you're asking for service recommendations. SO is primarily focused on helping with specific coding challenges and problems that you are able to present to us in a detailed way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For United States addresses, I doubt you'll find a free service because [USPS recommends](https://pe.usps.com/businessmail101?ViewName=CheckTheAddresses) using a certified vendor for NCOA and CASS-certified software.

But, there does look to be a USPS-hosted API that might give you address validation:
https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/address-information-api.htm

Looks like you have to register first to get access:
https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/welcome.htm